# creating support for a surface

Tags: 3d-design, support-structures, stl, blender

I created an stl file of bathymetry using Matlab and the results can be seen in the two pictures below in Blender. The problem I have is that it is very thin with overhangs. I would like to add some kind of support. For example put a solid block underneath it like in the third picture.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Blender and if I try to fix the stl file in Blender it puts a surface through my original surface. I also tried to use Microsoft 3D printing repair but it takes hours to queue.
How to I change my stl file so it has enough support to be printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generated a simple surface. You do however need a closed body to print. You might get away with using that surface as a cutter for a block and removing the top half, but there is an easier way using blender:

- Select the whole ara with `A`
- Extrude with `E` then `Z` to constrain direction
- pull until you have an item that is fully thick everywhere
- Scale the currently selected, extruded vertices with `S` then `Z` then `0` to force them all into the same plane
- possibly move the vertices down till they all are below the bottom surface

Now you have a positive thickness, solid body! Run a simple "remove double vertices" on this bottom if you want to reduce file size, but there you go! Export as STL and print!

Comment: This was a huge help. The first three steps were easy to follow. It was a bit difficult to scale it into the same plane, so I just added a cube and put that underneath it so it would support all.